# 'Select a measure:' stuck on 'Loading...' in Dashboard Designer KPI Dimensional Data Source Mapping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, dashboard-designer-2013, data-connection, kpi

I am trying to create a KPI in Dashboard Designer, but am getting a timeout. I have been doing this for a while on my site; this is not the first. I haven't had this problem before.

I created a new KPI and clicked on the Data Mappings column value, which is a hyperlink, to bring up the Dimensional Data Source Mapping dialog. I switched to a Data Connection in the site I just created (DC works perfectly and can retrieve sample data). When I click the "Select a measure:" drop-down menu, I get the message "Loading..." and after a while (a minute? two?) a dialog pops up with:

> The request took too long to complete. SharePoint is currently
>   unavailable or experiencing heavy traffic. Try again later.

This is a test SP server and I'm the only one on it, so there is no load. Also as mentioned, I am able to verify the Data Connection without problem. I am not having any issue with any of my other few dozen KPIs/Data Connections. Any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the SQL view so that it would return fewer rows overall, so the Data Source Mapping dialog would not time out.  The view now just returns records from the recent past, which is all I needed it for in the first place.